# Is it possible to manually pad a struct in order to isololate the variable you want to read/write to?

Tags: c, struct, padding, compiler-optimization

For example if I have the following struct located in a .h file and I need to access (read) the variable **Alerted**. How would I manually pad this struct so that I am able to access this variable?

```
struct _MYSTRUCT
{
    struct _DISPATCHER_HEADER Header;                              
    VOID* SListFaultAddress;                                        
    ULONGLONG QuantumTarget;                                        
    VOID* InitialStack;                                             
    VOID* volatile StackLimit;                                      
    VOID* StackBase;                                                
    ULONGLONG ThreadLock;                                           
    volatile ULONGLONG CycleTime;                                   
    ULONG CurrentRunTime;                                           
    ULONG ExpectedRunTime;                                          
    VOID* KernelStack;                                                
    struct _XSAVE_FORMAT* StateSaveArea;                     
    struct _KSCHEDULING_GROUP* volatile SchedulingGroup;     
    union _KWAIT_STATUS_REGISTER WaitRegister;               
    volatile UCHAR Running;                                  
    UCHAR Alerted[2];                                        
}
```

**EDIT:** I need to be able to access variables belonging to the _KTHREAD struct and I cannot find any documentation for this struct on Microsoft website. Please this project of mine is just for fun not going into production code of any sort.

Comment: What is this "manual padding" supposed to accomplish?  Why can't you access this field using the struct as is?

Comment: Please explain a little more about what you're actually trying to do.  Accessing members of structures is easy.  If anything, most people find that padding makes it harder.

Comment: You cannot access any member of the type `struct _MYSTRUCT` since it is a type, not an object (such as a variable). A type is just an abstract description of how we will use memory. If you have an object of that type, then, to manually pad the structure so you are able to access the member `Alerted`, do nothing, since you are already able to access the member. If `x` is an object of type `struct _MYSTRUCT`, you can access element `i` of the member `Alerted` by using `x.Alerted[i]`.

Comment: So what is `_KTHREAD` and how does it pertain to `_MYSTRUCT`?

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear why you can't use `object->alerted` directly, but it seems that you want to access `alerted` without specifying the name of the member, in this case you can use [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof), an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct T
{
    int a, b, c;
    unsigned char alerted[2];
};

static size_t offset = offsetof(struct T, alerted);

void func(void *object)
{
    printf("%c%c\n",
        ((unsigned char *)object + offset)[0],
        ((unsigned char *)object + offset)[1]
    );
}

int main(void)
{
    struct T t = {1, 2, 3, "ab"};

    func(&t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ab
```